# AngularJS - get the list of defined routes - $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am trying to implement `named routes`, so I don't have to write the whole path (often changes).

I was thinking I could get away with writing a service that would return the list of defined routes and a filter that would transform object to aroute

The use example would look like:

```
<a ng-href="{id:1}|route:'detail'">Click here!</a>
```

Provided I have added name:'detail' to my route definition, this would generate the following result :

```
<a href="#/detail/1/">Click here!</a>
```

I think this is quite simple, but:

**How can I get the list of defined routes ?**

I was thinking I can make use of `routeProvider` , but AFAIK it has no public methods or attributes I can access.

Comment: Finally someone else who realises something is lacking in angular. 

I love this about Django.

Comment: @airtonix, you can check out my solution below

Comment: @airtronix interesting.. IMO angular is like peas and django is like cornbread.  Sometimes the peas and cornbread are sort of weird when you eat them together, but one definitely isn't a substitute for the other-- i.e. https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/getting-started/WhatIsSails.md#what-is-sails

Answer (score 12, accepted):

turns out this is pretty straight forward:

http://plunker.co/edit/GNZxcvK4hfQ9LrlSvasK?p=preview

```
Components.filter('url', function ($route) {
  function resolveRoute(options, route) {
    var parts = route.split('/');
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
      var part = parts[i];
      if (part[0] === ':') {
        parts[i] = options[part.replace(':', '')];
        if (parts[i] == undefined) throw Error('Attribute \'' + part + '\' was not given for route \'' + route + '\'')
      }
    }
    return parts.join('/');
  }

  return function (options, routeName) {
    var routes = [];


    angular.forEach($route.routes,function (config,route) {
      if(config.name===routeName){
        routes.push(route);
      }
    });

    if (routes.length == 1) {
      return resolveRoute(options, routes[0]);
    }
    else if (routes.length == 0) {
      throw Error('Route ' + routeName + ' not found');
    }
    throw Error('Multiple routes matching ' + routeName + ' were found');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I took the liberty of packaging this up into a proper angular module: http://airtonix.github.io/angular-named-routes/

Comment: @g00fy just to clarify- $route.routes is what contains the array of all routes right?  I haven't tested in latest angular, but it appears that it doesn't work in legacy versions (tested in v1.2.16).  That makes sense of course, since ngRoute was pulled into a separate module, but worth pointing out in case it helps anyone.  Thanks for the answer!