# Build URLs based on routes

Tags: angularjs, url

Is there a way to build an URL based on the defined Angular routes? Something like Symfony does (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls).

Here is an example of how it would be used:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/document/:documentId', {
        name: 'document',
        templateUrl: 'partials/document.html',
        controller: 'documentController'
    });
}]);
```

Then in templates we could use something like:

```
<a href="{ $router.build('document', {documentId: 4567}) }">View document</a>
```

That would be compiled into:

```
<a href="/document/4567">View document</a>
```

Comment: Finally I found this piece of code than solves my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16368629/454615

Answer (score 0):

I have user $stateParams (from angular-ui-router) for this.

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.link = $stateParams.documentId;
});
```

[UI Router wiki on Github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)